# Node.js: How do I send json string from CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface

I am trying to send string(json format) from command line interface, Here I am facing problem.

```
$ node app.js custom-code {"name":"xxxxx","mobile":"xxxxxxxxxx"}

console.log(process.argv[3]) // {name:xxxxx,mobile:xxxxxxxxxx}-->unable to parse this
```

Expected:

```
{"name":"xxxxx","mobile":"xxxxxxxxxx"} // I can parse if i get this
```

What I needed is I should get the string as it is I entered in CLI.

Comment: Use single quote `'` to escape the json from being processed by the shell.

Comment: Single quote also not working as expected. I tried  backslash `{\"name\":\"xxxx\",\"mobile\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\"}` its working fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with node.js and only very little with json. It's a misunderstanding of the shell you're using.

Comment: Agreed. My suggestion is for bash shell and I've tested it. What shell are you using?

Comment: I am testing with windows command prompt.

Comment: @iLaYaツ - Have you solved this issue?

Comment: yes. As @hgoebl mentioned, it was related to shell